# Exclude rows that return NULL for a column when using a Case statement

Tags: t-sql, null, case

```
SELECT ir.objectid,ir.objecttype,ir.name,ir.email,ir.createdate,
CASE objecttype
    WHEN 1 THEN (select friendlyurl
        from locations
        where id = ir.objectid)
END as objecturl
FROM inforequests ir
WHERE createdate > '1/1/2014' 
order by CreateDate asc
```

This query returns 10 rows for me, but 1 row shows NULL for column `objecturl`, which happens if no record is found in the [locations] table.

How can I alter my query to make sure that when `objecturl` IS NULL, that row is not returned, so in my case my query would only return 9 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to the `WHERE` clause:

```
where createdate > '1/1/2014' and objecttype = 1
```

Since your `CASE` does not handle any other values, it will result in a NULL when `objecttype <> 1`.

Alternatively, you could nest `SELECT`s:

```
select *
  from ( SELECT ir.objectid,ir.objecttype,ir.name,ir.email,ir.createdate,
  CASE objecttype
      WHEN 1 THEN (select friendlyurl
          from locations
          where id = ir.objectid)
  END as objecturl
  FROM inforequests ir
  WHERE createdate > '1/1/2014' ) as Temp
where objecturl is not NULL
order by CreateDate asc
```

Note that this is somewhat different as it will also exclude rows for which the correlated subquery returns NULL.

Comment: Your first suggestion did not work for me, the nested solution did. Thanks!